# .gitignore Как добавить шаблон исключения на русском языке

Tags: git, gitignore

Следующий момент,

Хочу, чтобы репозиторий не захломляли всяким мусор в том числе файлами типа:

```
superFile - копия.xml
superGod - копия.qml
и тд.
```

Вношу игнорирования в .gitignore следующим образом

```
# Random files
*копия.qml
*копия.xml
*\320\272\320\276\320\277\320\270\321\217.xml
```

Последняя строчка, это как видит ее **git status**

Не работает. Как сделать, чтобы файлы под таким шаблоном игнорировались?

Comment: Ваш .gitignore сохранён в кодировке utf-8?

Comment: Нет, ANSI Cyrillic 1251. Спасибо за подсказку, как переконвертировал, все заработало!

Comment: А надо в utf-8.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, спасибо!

Comment: @AntonSavickiy оформите, пожалуйста, ответ для будущих посетителей.

Answer (score 1):

По совету [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)
Проверил кодировку файла .gitignore, оказалась ANSI Cyrillic 1251, после перекодировки в UFT8 все заработало как надо.